# Bibliography in TeXnicCenter

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texniccenter

How can I compile a project in TeXnicCenter, so that I'll get the bib references correctly. In a default installation of TeXnicCenter I don't see usage of BibTeX in any of the output profiles (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this picture of the output profile configuration, from http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html:

[image: output profiles]

The BibTeX setting is below the middle.

Comment: I see. For some reason when compiling with Ctr+F7 it involves the bibtex compilation, but with Ctr+F5 it doesn't.

Comment: In current versions of MiKTeX and TeX Live BibTeX and MakeIndex have got a security mechanism which doesn't allow absolute paths any more. Therefore `%bm` has to be replaced by `%tm` in the corresponding profile settings of TexnicCenter.

Comment: @jutky: Ctrl+F5 is only for viewing the output without compilation.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig, F5 is just for viewing, Ctl+F5 is "Build and View Output"!

Comment: @jutky: Oh, yes. Must have mixed that up.