# Cannot use biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have `32-bit miktex`, on Windows 7. I was using `bibtex`. Now I want to switch to `biblatex`. Using Miktex Package Manager(MPM), I installed `biblatex`.

MiKTeX Version: 2.9 32-bit.

I used the following example from docs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sortcites,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{wassenberg}.
\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]
\end{document}
```

However, the result I get on PDF document is: [Document](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2j-lQNEb56dZEd1ajlUWUFMN28/edit)

```
Filler text ().
```

Biblatex does not work properly. I checked the `.bib` file. And it seems correct. I don't get any `References` section in the pdf file.

PS: I cannot find the version of biblatex using MPM, how can I find it? (If necessary.)

### Question:

I'm not sure that I installed `biblatex` on my machine properly. What is the recommended way of doing it on a windows machine?

### EDIT: (Updated)

I changed `bibtex` to `biber` in the Texnic Center settings like as the same with the accepted answer. However, it still doesn't work.

Log File: (Updated)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2012.8.3)  7 AUG 2012 10:15
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/admin/Desktop/New*folder*(2)/91-sorting-schemes.tex
("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/New folder (2)/91-sorting-schemes.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf"
Language: english 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
\csq@reset=\count90
\csq@gtype=\count91
\csq@glevel=\count92
\csq@qlevel=\count93
\csq@maxlvl=\count94
\csq@tshold=\count95
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks15

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.def
File: csquotes.def 2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.cfg
File: csquotes.cfg 
))
(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2012/08/02 v2.1 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex2.sty
Package: biblatex2 2012/08/02 v2.1 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/A
B)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count96

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count97
\c@listtotal=\count98
\c@listcount=\count99
\c@liststart=\count100
\c@liststop=\count101
\c@citecount=\count102
\c@citetotal=\count103
\c@multicitecount=\count104
\c@multicitetotal=\count105
\c@instcount=\count106
\c@maxnames=\count107
\c@minnames=\count108
\c@maxitems=\count109
\c@minitems=\count110
\c@citecounter=\count111
\c@savedcitecounter=\count112
\c@uniquelist=\count113
\c@uniquename=\count114
\c@refsection=\count115
\c@refsegment=\count116
\c@maxextratitle=\count117
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count118
\c@maxextrayear=\count119
\c@maxextraalpha=\count120
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count121
\c@highnamepenalty=\count122
\c@lownamepenalty=\count123
\c@maxparens=\count124
\c@parenlevel=\count125
\blx@tempcnta=\count126
\blx@tempcntb=\count127
\blx@tempcntc=\count128
\blx@maxsection=\count129
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count130
\blx@notetype=\count131
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count132
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count133
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count134
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\shorthandwidth=\skip45
\biblabelsep=\skip46
\bibitemsep=\skip47
\bibnamesep=\skip48
\bibinitsep=\skip49
\bibparsep=\skip50
\bibhang=\skip51
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count135
\c@maxcomprange=\count136
\c@mincompwidth=\count137
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count138
\c@savedafterword=\count139
\c@annotator=\count140
\c@savedannotator=\count141
\c@author=\count142
\c@savedauthor=\count143
\c@bookauthor=\count144
\c@savedbookauthor=\count145
\c@commentator=\count146
\c@savedcommentator=\count147
\c@editor=\count148
\c@savededitor=\count149
\c@editora=\count150
\c@savededitora=\count151
\c@editorb=\count152
\c@savededitorb=\count153
\c@editorc=\count154
\c@savededitorc=\count155
\c@foreword=\count156
\c@savedforeword=\count157
\c@holder=\count158
\c@savedholder=\count159
\c@introduction=\count160
\c@savedintroduction=\count161
\c@namea=\count162
\c@savednamea=\count163
\c@nameb=\count164
\c@savednameb=\count165
\c@namec=\count166
\c@savednamec=\count167
\c@shortauthor=\count168
\c@savedshortauthor=\count169
\c@shorteditor=\count170
\c@savedshorteditor=\count171
\c@translator=\count172
\c@savedtranslator=\count173
\c@labelname=\count174
\c@savedlabelname=\count175
\c@institution=\count176
\c@savedinstitution=\count177
\c@lista=\count178
\c@savedlista=\count179
\c@listb=\count180
\c@savedlistb=\count181
\c@listc=\count182
\c@savedlistc=\count183
\c@listd=\count184
\c@savedlistd=\count185
\c@liste=\count186
\c@savedliste=\count187
\c@listf=\count188
\c@savedlistf=\count189
\c@location=\count190
\c@savedlocation=\count191
\c@organization=\count192
\c@savedorganization=\count193
\c@origlocation=\count194
\c@savedoriglocation=\count195
\c@origpublisher=\count196
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count197
\c@publisher=\count198
\c@savedpublisher=\count199
\c@language=\count200
\c@savedlanguage=\count201
\c@pageref=\count202
\c@savedpageref=\count203
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2012/08/02 v2.1 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count204
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count205
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count206
\c@smartand=\count207
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear.bb
x
File: authoryear.bbx 2012/08/02 v2.1 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2012/08/02 v2.1 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count208
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.cbx' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear.cb
x
File: authoryear.cbx 2012/08/02 v2.1 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2012/05/13 v6.82q Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `etexcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `kvsetkeys' (already loaded).
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\@linkdim=\dimen104
\Hy@linkcounter=\count209
\Hy@pagecounter=\count210

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2012/05/13 v6.82q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count211

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4067.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4070.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4077.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4082.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4300.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count212
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4653.
\Fld@menulength=\count213
\Field@Width=\dimen105
\Fld@charsize=\dimen106
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 5773.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 5778.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 5781.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 5788.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 5793.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 5798.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 5803.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 5843.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 5847.
\Hy@abspage=\count214
\c@Item=\count215
\c@Hfootnote=\count216
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2012/05/13 v6.82q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count217
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count218

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip52
)
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'american'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'american'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'american.lbx' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\american.lbx
File: american.lbx 2012/08/02 v2.1 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2012/08/02 v2.1 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)) ("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\91-sorting-schemes.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...


Package biblatex Warning: File '91-sorting-schemes.bbl' is wrong format version
 - expected 2.1.

Package biblatex Info: ... file '91-sorting-schemes.bbl' found.
("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\91-sorting-schemes.bbl"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.55   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.55   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.93   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.93   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.115   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.115   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.143   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 

l.143   \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 8.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 8.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box26
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 8.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count219
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 8.

("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\91-sorting-schemes.out")
("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\91-sorting-schemes.out")
\@outlinefile=\write4

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@tempb 

l.9 ...ite{wassenberg,cicero,companion,angenendt}.

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 11.
[1

{C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 11.

("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\91-sorting-schemes.aux")
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 11.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 11.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `91-sorting-schemes.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to '91-sorting-schemes.run.xml'.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9990 strings out of 494045
 162862 string characters out of 3145970
 565699 words of memory out of 3000000
 13215 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,35p,920b,1416s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600    ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on 91-sorting-schemes.pdf (1 page, 5224 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 26 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: You MWE includes a `backend=biber`. So you have to run biber to get your bibliography. Or change it to `backend=bibtex` (not so good ...).

Comment: What you mean by `run biber`?

Comment: PS: I tried changing it to `bibtex` now. It seems like it is working. However, you mentioned it is not recommended. What to do for using `biber` then?

Comment: Can you post the `.log` file?

Comment: Log file added.

Comment: The easy answer is - instead of running bibtex, run biber, it's a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your given MWE you call `biber`. Try `texdoc biber`to read more about it. To use `biber` in `TeXnicCenter` you can build a new profile with I suppose `Output` (I have a German TeXnicCenter) or perhaps `profile`. Then click `define profile` and change the call of `bibtex` to `biber`.

Compile three times with the new profile and `biber` should work.

You can also look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/bibliography-in-texniccenter).

---

You should also uncheck the box *Use BibTeX with this profile* checkbox on your new profile in TeXnicCenter. The result should look like:

[image: screenshot]

As usual, don't forget to run more than once :) to get the references right.

To find the version of your `biblatex` just have a look in your `log` file and search for something like this (taken from your posted `log`file):

```
(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2012/08/02 v2.1 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
```

It shows you that you have used `biblatex v2.1`.

Comment: We need to know which biber version you are using. It needs to be version 1.1 with biblatex 2.1.