# BibTeX and Jabref

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I have a bib file in Jabref.
Once the `.tex` file is compiled, the bibliography section appears but it is all empty.

Here is an example of my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book} 

\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}


\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{Bibpap3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Any insights ?

Comment: You seem to have no citations: do you have any in the real case? Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX?

Comment: I am a very beginner in Latex.
I did not at all use the \cite in the text, so there is no citation  using Jabref referecing, but I cite without linking to the reference. 
Should i use cite to make it work ? 
Second, how can I run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX? 

Sorry for trivial questions

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code is not a minimal working example (MWE), please see [I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Most of the packages can removed here for our test case. I do not know Jabref, but I think, you need to create a `bib` file first, what then must picked up by some LaTeX code. This is surely not related to TeXnicCenter.

Comment: BTW [Bibliography in TeXnicCenter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/bibliography-in-texniccenter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JabRef is a program for managing BibTeX database (`.bib`) files but does not directly affect what happens in LaTeX. Adding a database to a `.tex` file does not add in the citations. You need either `\cite` or `\nocite`: the latter adds references to the bibliography without a citation in the text

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{demo1,
  author = {Other, A. N.},
  journal = {J. Irrep. Res.},
  title = {Some things we did},
  year  = {2012},
}
@article{demo2,
  author = {Nobacon, D.},
  journal = {J. Chumb.},
  title = {Tubthumping},
  year  = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{demo1} more text\nocite{demo2}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

You will need to run LaTeX, then BibTeX, then LaTeX twice for the document to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

To run `BibTeX` just follow the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One additional source of this error is if you are citing multiple authors in one block, there can be no white-space between the authors.

This works:

```
\cite{smith2004,smith2005}
```

This does not work

```
\cite{smith2004, smith2005}
```